# How to pass the command via getopts argument and execute it?

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line-arguments, execution, getopts

I'm trying to make some application but it's too difficult to describe it here so I simplify my problem into simpler ones.

I just want to make a script that takes two arguments: time and command. It parses arguments with getopts, waits some time and executes the given command.

I've tried to use various combinations of double-quotes, single-quotes and no quotes at all, use bash arrays (I think so) and look for similar questions but it didn't help.

script.sh

```sh
time=1
command=""
while getopts "t:x:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    t) time=$OPTARG;;
    x) command=( "$OPTARG" );; # store the command in a variable
  esac
done
sleep $time
"${command[@]}" # execute the stored command
```

test.sh

```sh
# script to test arguments passing
echo "1$1 2$2 3$3 4$4"
```

The results of executing the script should be the same as the execution of command passed in -x argument.

```sh
$./script.sh -x "./test.sh a 'b c'"
1a 2'b 3c' 4 # actual results
$./test.sh a 'b c'
1a 2b c 3 4 # expected results
```

Comment: How about `command="$OPTARG";; ... bash -c "$command"`?

Comment: @melpomene it works and solves my problem... but can it have done without `bash` command?

Comment: Perhaps something involving `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `"${command[@]}"` to `eval "${command[0]}"`

Comment: I'd also switch to storing `command` as a plain variable instead of an array (you're just using the first element anyway).

Comment: Any-time you promote the use of `eval`, a kitten dies ;)

Comment: _My name is alf, i am from melmark_. But you are right - without eval it would be nicer!

Answer (score 0):

Solution without eval:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time=1
command=""
while getopts "t:x:" opt; do
  case "${opt}" in
    t)
      time="${OPTARG}"
      ;;
    x)
      command="${OPTARG}" # get the command

      # shift out already processed arguments
      shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"
      # and exit the getopts loop, so remaining arguments
      # are passed to the command
      break
      ;;
    *) exit 1 ;; # Unknown option
  esac
done

sleep "${time}"
"${command}" "${@}" # execute the command with its arguments
```

Comment: but then this command will not work: `./script.sh -x ./test.sh a "b c" -t 10`.
Your solution will interpret it like  `command="./test.sh a "b c" -t 10"`. Also `./script.sh -t 10 -x './test.sh a "b c"'` will not work.